# How do I make this game properly fullscreen?

Tags: python, pygame

```
import random
from time import sleep

import pygame


class InlineOverdrive:
    def __init__(self):

        pygame.init()
        self.display_width = 600
        self.display_height = 600
        self.black = (0, 0, 0)
        self.white = (255, 255, 255)
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.gameDisplay = None

        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):

        self.crash = False

        self.carImg = pygame.image.load('.\\img\\Car.png')
        self.car_x_coordinate = (self.display_width * 0.45)
        self.car_y_coordinate = (self.display_height * 0.8)
        self.car_width = 49


        # Background
        self.bgImg = pygame.image.load(".\\img\\Background.png")
        rect = self.bgImg.get_rect ()
        self.bg_x2 = 0
        self.bg_y2 = -600
        self.bg_x1 = 0
        self.bg_y1 = 0

        self.bg_speed = 3
        self.count = 0

    def car(self, car_x_coordinate, car_y_coordinate):
        self.gameDisplay.blit(self.carImg, (car_x_coordinate, car_y_coordinate))

    def racing_window(self):
        self.gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((self.display_width, self.display_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Inline Overdrive')
        self.run_car()

    def run_car(self):

        while not self.crash:

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                self.backgroundroad()
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self.crash = True
                # print(event)

                if (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
                    if (event.key == pygame.K_LEFT):
                        self.car_x_coordinate -= 50
                        print ("CAR X COORDINATES: %s" % self.car_x_coordinate)
                    if (event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT):
                        self.car_x_coordinate += 50
                        print ("CAR X COORDINATES: %s" % self.car_x_coordinate)
                    print ("x: {x}, y: {y}".format(x=self.car_x_coordinate, y=self.car_y_coordinate))

            self.gameDisplay.fill(self.black)
            self.backgroundroad()
            self.car(self.car_x_coordinate, self.car_y_coordinate)
            self.highscore(self.count)
            self.count += 1
            if (self.count % 100 == 0):
                self.bg_speed += 1

            if self.car_x_coordinate < 100 or self.car_x_coordinate > 360:
                self.crash = True
                self.display_message("You Have Crashed!")

            pygame.display.update()
            self.clock.tick(60)

    def display_message(self, msg):
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("NFS_by_JLTV.ttf", 72, True)
        text = font.render(msg, True, (255, 255, 255))
        self.gameDisplay.blit(text, (400 - text.get_width() // 2, 240 - text.get_height() // 2))
        pygame.display.update()
        self.clock.tick(60)
        sleep(1)
        inline_overdrive.initialize()
        inline_overdrive.racing_window()

    def backgroundroad(self):
        self.gameDisplay.blit(self.bgImg, (self.bg_x1, self.bg_y1))
        self.gameDisplay.blit(self.bgImg, (self.bg_x2, self.bg_y2))
        self.bg_y1 += self.bg_speed
        self.bg_y2 += self.bg_speed

        if self.bg_y1 >= self.display_height:
            self.bg_y1 = 0
        elif self.bg_y2 >= self.display_height:
            self.bg_y2 = 0

    def highscore(self, count):
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("NFS_by_JLTV.ttf", 20)
        text = font.render("SCORE : " + str(count), True, self.white)
        self.gameDisplay.blit(text, (0, 0))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    inline_overdrive = InlineOverdrive()
    inline_overdrive.racing_window()
```

I want this code to be able to loop the background infinitely as it moves along with the player. The screen currently does not scroll properly. The crash text is also not centered. How can I center it? If I can get my background to work properly, then my game is mostly complete. My car is also off screen for some reason. What needs to be done to make it be on the screen in the background?[Image of My Car](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdQfd.png) and [Image of My Background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0Dn8.png)

Comment: `font.render` gives `Surface()` (`text`) and `text.get_rect()` gives its `Rect()` (i.e `text_rect  = text.get_rect()`) with size and position. And you can put `text_rect` in center of screen using `text_rect.center = self.gameDisplay.get_rect().center`. And later you display it in center using `blit(text, text_rect)`

Answer (score 0):

To center text on screen (or on any other `Surface()`) you can use `Rect().center` and

```
text_rect.center = display_rect.center  # center on screen

text_rect.center = button_rect.center   # center on button
```

`font.render` gives `Surface()`, and it has `.get_rect()` to get `Rect()` with its size and position - at start it may have position `(0,0)` but `self.gameDisplay` is also a `Surface()` and it has `.get_rect()` which gives `Rect()` with its size and position. If you copy `.center` from `display` to `text_rect` then you will have centered `rect` and you can use it in `blit()` to center `text`

```
    def display_message(self, msg):
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("NFS_by_JLTV.ttf", 72, True)
        
        text_image = font.render(msg, True, (255, 255, 255))
        text_rect = text_image.get_rect()
        
        text_rect.center = self.gameDisplay.get_rect().center
        
        self.gameDisplay.blit(text_image, text_rect)

        # ... rest ...
```

---

As for background mistake is `self.bg_y1 = 0` and `self.bg_y2 = 0` because you have to set `-600` to put background above visible area.

```
        if self.bg_y1 >= self.display_height:
            self.bg_y1 = -600
            
        elif self.bg_y2 >= self.display_height:
            self.bg_y2 = -600
```

Maybe it would be simpler if you would use `Rect()` which has `.top` and `.bottom`

and you could set as start

```
        self.display_rect = self.gameDisplay.get_rect()

        self.bg2_rect.bottom = self.display_rect.top

        self.bg1_rect.bottom = self.display_rect.bottom
```

and later

```
        if self.bg1_rect.top >= self.display_rect.bottom:
            self.bg1_rect.bottom = self.display_rect.top
            
        elif self.bg2_rect.top >= self.display_rect.bottom:
            self.bg2_rect.bottom = self.display_rect.top
```

---

**BTW:**

`Rect()` has also `.left`, `.right`, `.centerx`, `.centery`, etc. It has also functions to detect collisions with point (ie. mouse position) - ie. `rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)` - or with other rectange - ie. `car_rect.colliderect( obstacle_rect )`